# Permission denied for user in group (group has directory write permissions)

Tags: files, permissions, rhel, debugging, fapolicyd

I'm getting Permission Denied when attempting to create/touch files in a directory with group ownership permissions.

touch /data/www/acoder.txt

```
[acoder@box]$ touch /data/www/acoder.txt
touch: cannot touch '/data/www/acoder.txt': Permission denied
```

cat /etc/group

```
webdev:x:1001:acoder
```

`id` shows I am in group webdev:

```
[acoder@box ~]$ id
uid=1000(acoder) gid=1000(acoder) groups=1000(acoder),10(wheel),1002(webdev) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

ll -lZ /data/

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache webdev system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 4096 Mar 20 15:39 www
```

namei -olm /data/www

```
[acoder@box ~]$ namei -olm /data/www
f: /data/www
dr-xr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   data
drwxrwx--- apache webdev www
```

If acoder is in group `webdev`, and `webdev` has group ownership (including write permissions) of the containing directory, what else could be triggering the Permission Denied error?

**EDIT**

Located a reference to `touch` with auseach:

> time->Tue Mar 21 09:21:15 2023
>
> node=box.example.com type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1679404875.375:8966252):
> proctitle=746F756368002F646174612F7777772F6164726961322E747874
>
> node=box.example.com type=PATH msg=audit(1679404875.375:8966252):
> item=0 name="/data/www/" inode=128 dev=fd:0e mode=040755 ouid=48
> ogid=1002 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
> nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
>
> node=box.example.com type=CWD msg=audit(1679404875.375:8966252):
> cwd="/home/acoder"
>
> node=box.example.com type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1679404875.375:8966252):
> arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c
> a1=7fff2ee2e64b a2=941 a3=1b6 items=1 ppid=602556 pid=602594 auid=1000
> uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000
> fsgid=1000 tty=pts25 ses=1 comm="touch" exe="/usr/bin/touch"
> subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
> key="access"

Also getting error -1 if the user acoder attempts to upload a file to `/data/www/` with `sftp`

> time->Tue Mar 21 09:30:14 2023
>
> node=box.example.com type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> proctitle="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
>
> node=box.example.com type=PATH msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> item=1 name="/data/www/" inode=536875051 dev=fd:0e mode=040770 ouid=48
> ogid=1002 rdev=00:00
> obj=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 nametype=PARENT
> cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
>
> node=box.example.com type=PATH msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> item=0 name="/data/www/acoder.php" inode=626000347 dev=fd:0e
> mode=0100660 ouid=48 ogid=1002 rdev=00:00
> obj=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 nametype=NORMAL
> cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
>
> node=box.example.com type=CWD msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> cwd="/home/acoder"
>
> node=box.example.com type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=no exit=-1 a0=ffffff9c
> a1=561c6002f6e0 a2=241 a3=1b6 items=2 ppid=602648 pid=602649 auid=1000
> uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000
> fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=3674 comm="sftp-server"
> exe="/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server"
> subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
> key="access"
>
> node=box.example.com type=FANOTIFY msg=audit(1679405414.563:8966285):
> resp=2
>
> [root@box]#

In both instances I'm seeing where asearch shows context as

```
subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

but the actual context on the filesystem is

```
context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

According to [RHEL docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files),

> subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>
> The subj field records the SELinux context **with which the analyzed
> process was labeled at the time of execution**.

I'm confused on what this means exactly. Is SELinux reading the context as different from what I am seeing with `ll -lZ`?

Both ausearch results reference `syscall=257`, 257 is `openat` per `ausyscall`.

`audit2allow` isn't suggesting an relevant policy changes:

```
[root@box]# ausearch -c 'touch' --raw | audit2allow -M my-touch
Nothing to do
[root@box]#
```

**EDIT 2 (March 24, 2023)**

Believe I've narrowed down the problem to [fapolicyd](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening). If I stop this service, I can sftp the file. It has to be running however, so I need to learn how to configure it in allowing access to sftp (and probably other processes I haven't unconvered yet)

Any more ideas?

Comment: `ll -lZ` contains `system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0`. This means your machine is using SELinux. That might be causing the `EPERM`. I've never used it before, but I found this article from Red Hat describing how to troubleshoot: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/diagnose-selinux-violations

Comment: The answer above is more of a comment, but I did use `auseach` to find where touch is generating an error 13. audit2allow isn't generating anything helpful however. More info added to my question above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; in your `ll -lZ /data/` output, you show that the `www` directory is owned by apache:webdev, but it also shows that the webdev group does *NOT* have write permissions. Is that a copy/paste problem?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes type-o

Comment: Looks like this is `fapolicyd` related. I've never worked with fapolicy as it looks relatively new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an `fapolicyd` denial.

Not sure if this is considered best practice but I fixed this by

Add new rule:

```
# fapolicyd-cli --file add /data/www/nbsprod/public_html/ --trust-file nbsprod_pub_html
```

Update rules with `fapolicyd-cli`

```
# fapolicyd-cli --update
```

Verify that `fapolicyd` is set to run in enforcing mode (not permissive)

```
# vi /etc/fapolicyd/fapolicyd.conf

...
permissive = 0
...
```

Restart `fapolicyd`

```
# fapolicyd-cli --update
```

End user now able to upload scripts to the www directory specified above with `fapolicyd` running in deny mode.